# Perforce Batch Script

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-integrate, perforce-branch-spec

Hi I am trying to write a batch script that copies same set of configuration files from one application in depot to another application (trigger for copying those files once checked into first application). The idea in my mind is:

1. Add files from first application to client using p4 add
2. use p4 copy
3. p4 submit

Is this the right approach? Please help. Please provide any sample scripts available.

Answer (score 0):

After trying for sometime, I was able to figure it out. The method I used is

1. create a new workspace
2. sync the files to workspace
3. copy the files using p4 copy and
4. submit the changes.

Comment: Please accept your answer if you don't expect to get better ones. Click on the tick left of your answer.